Custom Quantum Gate equivalence to backend basis gate set
Hello I am using Qiskit and I have defined a custom gate which implements the array shown in the image:

This array is unitary and the function R(theta) works by tuning a continious variable into 0 of 1 so then the exponential is in Ising {-1,1}. I provide the code i used for the array and the custom gate:
class DiagUGate(Gate): # The gates must be defined like this
    def __init__(self, num_qubits: int = None, params: list = None, label: str = None):
        if params is None:
            params = []
        super().__init__('unitary', num_qubits, params, label=label)
    def _define(self):
        from qiskit.circuit.quantumcircuit import QuantumCircuit
        from qiskit.circuit.library import PhaseGate, U3Gate, UnitaryGate
        defn = QuantumCircuit(self.num_qubits)
        unitary_array = np.zeros([len(self.params), len(self.params)], dtype=complex)
        for i, theta in enumerate(self.params):
            if 0<= theta < np.pi:
                unitary_array[i, i] = 1
            if np.pi <=theta <2*np.pi:
                unitary_array[i, i] = -1
        diagonal_gate = UnitaryGate(unitary_array)
        defn.append(diagonal_gate,[i for i in range(self.num_qubits)])
        self.definition = defn
    def __array__(self, dtype=None, copy = None): # This enables the Gate.to_matrix() code line
        if copy is False:
            raise ValueError('unable to avoid cioy while creating array request')
        unitary_array = np.zeros([len(self.params), len(self.params)], dtype=complex)
        for i, theta in enumerate(self.params):
            if 0<= theta < np.pi:
                unitary_array[i, i] = 1
            if np.pi <=theta <2*np.pi:
                unitary_array[i, i] = -1
        return unitary_array

For the example I am studying I have 2 qubits and 4 parameters theta. My question is: How can I transpile and translate this qustom gate into a backend?
I am using AerSimulator() as my backend for simplicity purposes and I don't know how I can define or get the equivalence so I can update the SessionEquivalence library.
Thanks in advance!!

You can implement this in qiskit with a single line of code without having to build a custom gate:
qc.append(DiagonalGate(np.sign(np.pi - angles)),range(n))
Here, qc is the QuantumCircuit you want to append your gate to, angles the list of angles, and n the number of qubits. Here is an example of how it works:
import numpy as np
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.circuit.library import DiagonalGate
from qiskit.quantum_info import Operator

n = 3                                         # arbitrary number of qubits
angles = np.random.uniform(0, 2*np.pi, 2**n)  # random list of angles (as an example)

qc = QuantumCircuit(n)
qc.append(DiagonalGate(np.sign(np.pi - angles)),range(n))
Operator(qc)

Running this code generated this list of angles:
[0.44579945, 3.15032481, 4.37191909, 4.47559583, 0.90522884, 1.07373175, 3.23045685, 0.2911079], which as expected, resulted in the following unitary matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0  \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Thanks for the help. However, I need the angles to be of the class Parameter so I can run  a Quantum Variational algorithm with them. Knowing this do you have any idea on how to transpile a custom quantum parameterized gate to any backend, because i am encountering problems because of the logical operations between the thetas (Parameter class) and the float/int (np.pi,0...).

I think I have an idea of how to do it, but the issue is that you never specified that your angles needed to be of type Parameter in your original question. In the code you shared, your constructor has them as being of type list: params: list = None. Please make sure your question describes what is it exactly that you are trying to accomplish.

Hi, I have corrected the error and selected the params as a ParameterVector element. No i have transpiled it but he Hamiltonian will not apply to layout and show the error: hamilton_isa = Hamiltonian.apply_layout(qc_transpiled, num_qubits=2).
